# Please help me identify the ICs on this Board

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have the following module which can be found on this website :- http://www.elecrow.com/uart-ttl-to-rs485-twoway-converter-p-1545.html

It is simply a bidirectional Uart TTL to RS485 converter. I have included the images below. The 8 pin small ic (U1) is RS485 which is itself unidirectional. I need help in identifying the second chip (U2), the one with 14 pins. This ic is responsible for switching between transmission and reception mode of the 485 ic. I have the module with me but the name of the ic has been erased. Plus there is no datasheet for the module available on the website. Could anyone please suggest what is the name of this ic??

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess, it's a cheap MCU or FPGA. It has to detect TX and enable transmit of U1. After the send is complete it has tu switch to receive. Kind of autobaudrate detector and timer.

Comment: Take some fuming nitric acid, decap the 14 pin device, and stick the die under a microscope. Anything else is going to be guesswork.

Comment: The bastards removed the Chip id.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added bottom layer

[image: Added bottom layer]

Surely it must drive DE/RE pin (SOIC8 2 and 3) of transceiver depending from TXD (if TXD is LOW then DE/RE HIGH).